# Selecting a psuedo element using adjacent sibling selector

Tags: html, css

I have an element which can have an `--active` class added to it, via a toggle button using JS.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element element--active"></div>
  ::after
</div>
```

When this class is added, I would like the `::after` element to be `display:none;`

The following won't work,

```
.element--active + ::after {
  display: none;
}
```

But why is this?

Is my alternative just adding another class to the container when `element--active` is added?

Comment: Are you wanting the after of the parent container to be `display:none`?  If so, you can't do this with css as there is no parent selector.  I would put the active class on the container instead (if it only contains one element or as well as if it contains multiple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.element--active + ::after` is the same as `.element--active + *::after`

So it finds an element which is a member of the `element--active` class. Then it finds its adjacent sibling. It doesn't have one. So it stops.

If you want the pseudo-element after `.element--active` then you would just use `.element--active::after`.

If you want the pseudo-element after `.container`, then you are stuck because CSS doesn't have a parent selector.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because `::after` is a psuedo element of `.container`. Since you can't select a parent in CSS, a solution could be to add the class to `.container` and then removing the `::after` element.